# Segregating title into words and searching it in a another title

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I was trying to automate an Excel file which has title in both A and B columns and I have to search each word from A within B. If any words matches then I need to paste it after B column which is available (C, D, ...) at the same row.

I was using the below code for which I will be segregating the words manually in a separate column of column A title and searching it in column B.

```
Dim a() As String
Dim b() As String
Dim aRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer, clm As Integer

Set aRng = Range(Range("KW1"), Range("KW1").End(xlDown))

For Each cel In aRng
    a = Split(cel, " ")
    b = Split(cel.Offset(, 1), " ")
    clm = 2

    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        For t = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
            If UCase(a(i)) = UCase(b(t)) Then
                cel.Offset(, clm) = a(i)
                clm = clm + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

Next
```

but it repeating duplicate words again and again if any.
Is there a way to avoid duplicate words? Please help me out.

Comment: So it needs to print *every* word that matches between A and B? I'd say use some arrays. If you want to avoid duplicates, use a dictionary - but you'll need to clear it after each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really the cleanest method, but you could just check each populated cell by looping through them from an offset of 2 until you reach an empty cell.  Note that this code is untested.

```
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    For t = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
        If UCase(a(i)) = UCase(b(t)) Then
            clm = 2
            Do While True
                If UCase(cel.Offset(, clm)) = UCase(a(i)) Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                If cel.Offset(, clm) = "" Then
                    cel.Offset(, clm) = a(i)
                    Exit Do
                End If
                clm = clm + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi Jason i was trying to use for loop instead of do while in the above code and i got confused. Could you please help me out?

Comment: The Do While works because it loops until it finds an empty cell.  To use a For loop, you'd have to find the last used cell in that row and loop from 2 to that column + 1, or you'd just have to loop through every column of that row and exit when you find a match or reach an empty cell.  To do the latter, change the `Do While True` statement to `For clm = 2 to cel.EntireRow.Cells.Count`, change the `Loop` statement to `Next`, change both `Exit Do` statements to `Exit For`, and eliminate the `clm = clm + 1` statement.

Comment: Hi again Jason, now I'm calculating percentage the title matches with column B by using the below code. However i couldn't able get the exact  no of word in column A and the exact number words matches with column B. 

Could you please check the code and correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Sub percentage()`

Dim a() As String
Dim b() As String
Dim aRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer, clm As Integer
Set aRng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A65536").End(xlDown))

For Each cel In aRng
    a = Split(cel, " ")
    b = Split(cel.Offset(, 1), " ")
    d = 0
    clm = 2
    C = UBound(a)
If cel.Value <> "" Then
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)

```
        For t = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
            If UCase(a(i)) = UCase(b(t)) Then
                clm = 2
             Do While True
                If UCase(cel.Offset(, clm)) = UCase(a(i)) Then
                Exit Do
                End If
                    If cel.Offset(, clm) = "" Then
                        'cel.Offset(, clm) = a(i)
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    clm = clm + 1
                Loop
                d = d + 1
            End If

        Next

Next
```

`MsgBox "Total words " & C & " Matched words " & d
'cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = (d / c)
End If
Next

End Sub`